# Open AI finish response LENGTH

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai

I am calling open AI api with below details and I am getting below response

```
 {'value': {'outputs': [{'finishReason': 'LENGTH', 'text': '\n\nThe summary in this JSON format is as follows:\n\nshort_', 'generationTimestamp': 1689303489, 'trackingId': "Ê.\x00Õ!07´a'"}], 'modelId': 'TEXT_ADA_001'}}
```

My parameters:

```
 {
"model_max_tokens": 1024,
"model_id": "TEXT_DAVINCI_003",
"model_temperature": 0
}
```

Prompt text length is 5903

Response is not complete message and finishReason is stop, How can Handle this and get desired results ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided information, it seems like you're using `TEXT_DAVINCI_003` and your prompt token length is `5903`.

I have reproduced similar scenario with similar prompt token length.
[image]

The model's max context length is `4097 Tokens` ("completion_tokens" + "prompt_tokens") and you're request length is 6927 (1024 + 5903) which is higher than the allowed length.

To fix this please reduce the length of your prompt text.
[image]

If you want to work with higher prompt text length, you can use other models which support higher token length.
Please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/concepts/models#model-updates) for details on other models.